# Infinite Jump how to limit the Jump?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using these script and the jump seems fine but the problem is I can do infinite Jump, how to limit the jump?

Like... I only want to jump once and jump again after hit the ground, not jump in the air, nor double jump...

```
Public void jumping()
{
    if (GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Character - Idle - Nina"))
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Jump");
    }

    if (GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Character - Run - Nina"))
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Jump");
    }

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, jump);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a boolean variable like **canJump**. when you collide with ground it should be true. When you press space for jump, if your canJump variable true, you can start jump anim then set your **canJump** variable **false**

```
bool canJump;
float force=10f;//it is an example try for better 

Public void jumping()
{
    if(canJump){

        if (GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Character - Idle - Nina"))
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Jump");
        }

        if (GetComponent<Animator> 
 ().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Character - Run - Nina"))
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Jump");
        }

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector3.up*force);


       canJump=false;
    }
}


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){

    if(collision.gameObject.compareTag("ground")){
        canJump=true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh no, i figure it out, but it still doesnt work, i still can fly with up arrow key

Comment: just copy OnCollisionEnter function and paste on your script. add colliders your player and ground. if you are developing 2d game. add 2D after function **OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)** and add only collision with 2D affix your player and ground.

Comment: so i need to add ```void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){

    if(collision.gameObject.compareTag("ground")){
        canJump=true;
    }
```
to my Ground and add the script?

Comment: no. add it to your player script where your jump function

Comment: I've add this to my Player Script
```void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            canJump = true;
        }
    }
```

and also i've add ```canJump = false;``` inside ```void jumping()```

But sorry it's not working... i still able to fly it...

Comment: I've realized yet. you should add force your rigidbody not velocity. velocity is contineus and it will contineu moving your player to up. so,, I updated my answer and found better and well clarified answer. [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58378912/8784762)

Comment: Thankyou very much for helping me out, i really appreciate it, but i think i'll just remove Jump Button, it's really complicated for a Noob like me xD